# Google Apps Script Time Based Trigger Date and Hour

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, clock

I can add a time-driven trigger to run on a specific date **and time** manually via the resources menu, but I cannot find how to do it programatically. I have the .at(date) method, but to this I would like to add a specific time. Is that possible programatically?

Example from the documentation:

```
 // Creates a trigger for December 1, 2012
 var triggerDay = new Date(2012, 11, 1);
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .at(triggerDay)
   .create();
```

Can "myFunction" be run on Decemeber 1, 2012 **at 7 am**?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Read the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date object can take a time value in its constructor.

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

The trigger will run +- 15 minutes from the specified time.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I tried that before, but I think my syntax was off.