# How to schedule a trigger on a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The situation:**
I have sheet containing JSON data that collects personal trading information from a stock exchange. When this API feed retrieves a new line of information (after a new trade has been placed) I need that to act as a trigger to run two Google Scripts to perform their function. These scripts can only be triggered when a new trade has been made, not on a regular time-based trigger.

**What have I tried:**
Initially, I started off trying onChange/onEdit however, both options will not work because onChange/onEdit search for user-made edits to the cell, which changes to an API feed are not. Because there is no material change to the formula and therefore onChange/onEdit do not react to trigger the script. I have also tried to find a solution for a trigger to activate a script on changes made within a formula (therefore to allow for new data to arriving through an API to trigger the script), but that doesn't appear to be possible.

**What am I trying to achieve right now:**
I am considering the possibility of establishing a time scheduled trigger via Scripts. Within the API feed, I get confirmation of the date and time a trade has been made. I plan for the script to search the lastRow of certain columns to identify a date and time to trigger this time scheduled script, which in turn will trigger the two other scripts mentioned above.

**My coding**:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger on 2019-12-11 at 21:00.
ScriptApp.newTrigger('priceCalc')
    .timeBased()
    .atDate(2019, 12, 11)
    .atHour(21)
    .create();
}
```

**Explanation on coding**:
Eventually, the information held within the .atDate() and .atHour() strings will contain information drawn from the lastRow of different columns on Google Sheets to identify the correct integer to feed in to this script. But for now, I am just trying to get this script to work based on fixed values.

In this example above, on 11th December 2019 at 21:00, the createTimeDrivenTriggers script should be triggered, which in turn runs the priceCalc script.

**Questions**:
1) I cannot get this script to work correctly at the date/time given. What am I doing wrong?
2) I also need to incorporate an .atMinute() and .atSecond() strings here, but that doesn't seem to be available. Can anyone advise how to incorporate this?
3) Finally, if anyone can think of a better way to find a solution for this other than a time scheduled trigger, I am happy to consider other options.

I am very much a novice of scripts, so helpful advise to sort my issue would be greatly appreciated. I have spent days trying to find a solution without any luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script Time Based Trigger Date and Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448784/google-apps-script-time-based-trigger-date-and-hour)

Answer (score 1):

### You can not use `atDate(year, month, day)` and `atHour(hour)` together

Indeed, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#athourhour) specifies:

> Frequency is required if you are using atHour() or nearMinute()

Instead, you can use [at(date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atdate) with a date-time string, with the corresponding [Javascript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

*Sample:*

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger on 2019-12-11 at 21:00.  
  var time=new Date('2019-12-12T21:00:00');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('priceCalc')
    .timeBased()
    .at(time)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204780/discussion-on-answer-by-ziganotschka-how-to-schedule-a-trigger-on-a-script).

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code, it generates an error message:

> Already chosen a specific date time with at() or atDate()....

What it means is that you cannot use **both** `atDate()` **and** `atHour()` in the same script.

The solution to creating a "time-of-day-and-hour" trigger is to use `at()`.

- The benefit of this is that you can specify a time interval down to seconds and milliseconds.
- However, do not be misled. Google undertakes that the script will execute within +/-15 minutes from the specified time. So incorporating "second" parameters might make you feel good, but isn't guaranteed to make any real difference.

Props: @SpencerEaston (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30458103/1330560) for the definition of the date which may well be in the documentation, but I couldn't see it.

For example:

---

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger on 2019-12-12 at 21:00.
  //var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
  var d = new Date(2019, 12, 12, 21, 00, 00, 00);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('triggertest')
    .timeBased()
    .at(d)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer was really similar to ziganotschka so I will answer by answers with the same reply... I've been testing and working on this all day with some mixed results. First of all, I seemed to have greater success with the format var time=new Date('2019-12-12T21:00:00'), however it almost seems random as to when the script wants to work and not.

Comment: I now have this set up so that line says: var time=new Date("Overview!$AA$1"); where Overview!AA1 is formated as shown above. The script would not seem to work unless I run the createTimeDrivenTriggers first. Therefore, in Overview!AA1, I have the formula =INDEX('Trade API'!S:S,MAX(ROW('Trade API'!S:S)*('Trade API'!S:S<>"")))+0.01. This searches and displays the last trade date/time in the list of trades and add 15 minutes to the trade time.

Comment: I then have createTimeDrivenTriggers on a standard 5 minute time trigger (my thinking behind this is that this runs the script constantly and finds a change in Overview!AA1 if there is one before the trade time +15 minutes time arrives.However, results seem completely random. Sometimes priceCalc can be triggered before, sometime after, sometimes multiple times (it is important that priceCalc function only triggers once because it takes a snapshot of data and it can't be duplicated), and sometimes never. It seems completely random. Is there something here that I am doing incorrectly?