# Exact Time Trigger in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, clock

I'm using Google Apps Script on a Google Sheet. I want to run a script at an exact time (15:20 GMT+2). I found the code at [Google Apps Script Time Based Trigger Date and Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448784/google-apps-script-time-based-trigger-date-and-hour). I ran the script at 3:15 pm with no errors. I'm still not understanding, why at 3:20 pm no changes at the document happened. Could anyone help me?

```
     function DK_Dienstag_unblock_1000(unblock1000){
function setTrigger() {

deleteTriggers();  
scheduledTrigger(15,20);
}

function scheduledTrigger(hours,minutes){
  
var today_D = new Date();
var year = today_D.getFullYear();
var month = today_D.getMonth();
var day = today_D.getDate();
  
pars = [year,month,day,hours,minutes];
  
var scheduled_D = new Date(...pars);
var hours_remain=Math.abs(scheduled_D - today_D) / 36e5;
ScriptApp.newTrigger("function_Triggered")
.timeBased()
.after(hours_remain * 60 *60 * 1000)
.create()
}

function deleteTriggers() {
  
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  if (   triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "function_Triggered") {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
}

function function_Triggered() {
 // your function code here - delete protected range + delete content in C4
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hVgGsCQobn-7Igw0Sc0TdkupjO16RffquZWxmGENUv0');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // assuming you want the first sheet
var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  if (protections[i].getDescription() == 'Anmeldung') { //name of protected range
    protections[i].remove();
  }
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})
  .setFontSize(10).setFontWeight(null);
}}}
```

Comment: Please read you link carefully it says `The trigger will run +- 15 minutes from the specified time.`

Comment: nearMinute(minute)

Specifies the minute at which the trigger runs **(plus or minus 15 minutes).**